# Why is boostrap affix jumping to the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have found that when reaching the bottom of the page and then scrolling back up slightly.. the affix'd sidebar will jump back to the top and become static again.

Please check demo at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/epnfzo4s/1/).

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">

            <div id="1" class="test-div">
                <h2>Header</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="2" class="test-div">
                <h2>Header</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="3" class="test-div">
                <h2>Header</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="4" class="test-div">
                <h2>Header</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="5" class="test-div">
                <h2>Header</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="6" class="test-div">
                <h2>Header</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="7" class="test-div">
                <h2>Header</h2>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="60" data-offset-bottom="400" class="submenu">
              sub menu will go here<br>
              sub menu will go here<br>
              sub menu will go here<br>
              sub menu will go here<br>
              sub menu will go here<br>
              sub menu will go here<br>
              sub menu will go here<br>
              sub menu will go here<br>
              sub menu will go here<br>
              sub menu will go here<br>
              sub menu will go here<br>
              sub menu will go here<br>
              sub menu will go here<br>
              sub menu will go here<br>
              sub menu will go here<br>
              sub menu will go here<br>
              sub menu will go here<br>
              sub menu will go here<br>
              sub menu will go here<br>
              sub menu will go here<br>
              sub menu will go here<br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 footer">Footer</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    padding-top: 200px;
}
.test-div {
    min-height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid #D1D1D1;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.footer {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `data-offset-bottom`, you need to add an appropriate css classes to handle that - as per the Bootrap documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix

> If a bottom offset is defined, scrolling past it should replace .affix
>   with .affix-bottom. Since offsets are optional, setting one requires
>   you to set the appropriate CSS. In this case, add position: absolute;
>   when necessary. The plugin uses the data attribute or JavaScript
>   option to determine where to position the element from there.

So if you add this css

```
    .affix-bottom {
        position: absolute;
    }
```

you'll find it starts working.

http://jsfiddle.net/epnfzo4s/2/